Generalized additive model which interacts with mean of response
I am currently constructing a model to predict house prices based on the GAM framework.
The model is based on fitting a data set of 222299 house sales with the following information:
Response variable: 
House price per square meter, P
Covariates: 
Coordinates, (x,y) 
Sales date, t (converted to an integer) 
Building size, A 
Lot size, L
Loosely stated my question is: Is it possible to construct a model, where the fitted value of P itself enters as a parameter in the model?
To understand what exactly I mean by this I think it is helpful to explain the 3-step strategy I currently use for modelling.
Step 1: I first fit a non-interacting model to my data set:
model_noninteracting <- mgcv::bam(P ~ s(x, y, k = 4000) +
                                      s(t, k = 10, pc = 0) +
                                      s(Y, k = 8, pc = 1970) +
                                      s(A, k = 5, pc = 140) +                                   
                                      s(L, k = 5, pc = 800),
                                  data = data,
                                  family = tw(link=log),
                                  method = "fREML")

Step 2: I then use this model to generate an initial "guess" for the price of a given house. The guesses are grouped into different price categories reflecting a cheap, standard and expensive house, which are converted to factors.
dataset$predictions <- predict.gam(model_noninteracting, dataset, type = "response")
price_levels <- c(0, 10000, 20000, 200000)
dataset <- dataset %>% mutate(category = cut(predictions, breaks = price_levels)) 
dataset$category <- as.factor(dataset$category)

Step 3: I finally fit an interacting model, where the price-category is used for modelling houses across different price categories.
model_interacting <- mgcv::bam(P ~ s(x, y, k = 4000) +
                                   s(t, k = 10, pc = 0, by = category) +
                                   s(Y, k = 8, pc = 1970, by = category) +
                                   s(A, k = 5, pc = 140, by = category) +                                   
                                   s(L, k = 5, pc = 800, by = category),
                                   data = data,
                                   family = tw(link=log),
                                   method = "fREML")

The idea of the above is of course based on the idea that houses behave differently across different price categories, and I have verified that the final model obtained from this rather "homemade" 3-step procedure outperforms simpler models. However, the whole process is at the end of the day a bit clumsy and I can't help but think, that there ought to be a model-fitting strategy with GAMs which achieves something like the above in a more elegant way. I would love to hear your opinions about this.
Thanks in advance

Using the response as covariate implies a lot of overfit. The question is also how you would apply the model to new observations. Furthermore, it seems there is no clean validation strategy.

@MichaelM. It is not the response I use directly, but rather the fitted values obtained from the non-interacting model. So on new observations I would first apply the non-interacting model and then use its prediction as input to the interacting model.

@AugustEdwards That's nitpicking; it may not be the actual response but it will be a reasonable approximation of the response. You're still using the response to predict itself.

@MichaelM for new observations, one observes the covariates from the first model to obtain the initial guess for the new observations, assign it a price band category, and then run this all through the step 3 model. his sounds like a nightmare to evaluate statistically, but not impossible to actually do it.

So you would not recommend the idea? Notice that the interval of prices for each of the three categories that I use is rather broad, so I would not say that it corresponds to using the response to predict itself (i.e. overfitting). The latter would however become a concern if I constructed more categories with increasingly smaller price bands. In any case, it appears a perfectly valid approach to me (although it might be a nightmare to evaluate statistically, as you say) if I am careful to validate the model on an out-of-sample validation test to detect overfitting.

I don't think this model has good properties, yes. For instance, the prediction function will have large jumps even for small changes in a covariate. Then why not directly use a strong ML model, I am wondering?

Some thoughts, along the lines of @Michael M:

If you can assign the fitted prices to a category, you can use that same process, surely (!), to place the observed house prices into the same categories. But of course the problem would be what to then do for new observations?

But regardless, you are using the response to predict itself and that suggests you will be overfitting.

One problem with what you wrote will be assessing the uncertainty in your predictions; there's nothing propagating the uncertainty from the first model into the second model.

Don't the price bands vary with region; what's expensive on one location isn't expensive in another. So how are you accounting for this?



Two things I thought might work are (although I think the second option would be better):

Assign the price category to the observed data, fit the full model, and then when you come to do predictions for new observations, generate three prediction for each observation, one per category.

Or model the price category (response is then an ordered categorical) using the categories that you assign to houses at hand. Then, for new observations you have two steps:

use the covariates to predict the price category, and then
predict from your "interaction" model using the predicted category (the category with the highest posterior probability)

Instead of the final prediction for a new observation of using the category with the highest posterior probability, you could create a weighted average of the predicted prices for all three categories, using the predicted probabilities of each price category as weights.
This way you aren't using the response to predict itself; you are assigning price bands using your domain knowledge, then building two models; one to predict the price band and then one to predict price given the price band.
Using posterior simulation you could start to quantify the uncertainty and propagate it from one model to the next, but it's going to be computationally expensive; my initial though would require you to refit the price model (the model in your step 3) for each posterior draw from the model for the price category.



I actually think you should consult a local statistician who can advise you more closely than is possible through a site like CV. It would be very easy to go wrong here and not know it.
